# A statistic to describe a correlation with progression

Tags: correlation, spss, survey, proportion

I want to see if the `proportion of 'I don't know'` responses correlates with the progression through the survey. Generally we expect this proportion to increase through the survey due to a fatigue effect. However, the following chart suggests this effect is not present in my data:

[image]

I would however like to back this up with a statistic. I figure I need a `correlation` measure between the question order and proportion of DK. Does anyone know about such measure, and maybe how to produce it in `SPSS` (R could also be an option)?

PS: I eventually also want to control for question and respondent characteristics.

Comment: Are there also drop-outs?  If fatigued people drop out that might explain why the don't know rate doesn't increase.  The other issue to look for is the complexity of questions.  If the easy questions are last you wouldn't expect an increasing rate.  The only way to be sure in testing this would be if the questions, or at least groups of questions where they are linked, were in random order, which is often undesirable for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside my comment on drop-outs, which should be considered together with this if there are any; I would start with a scatterplot of proportion of don't know versus question rank; and follow up with Spearman's rank correlation coefficient.

A better approach would also take into account complexity of questions.  One way of doing this might be to use data (if you have it) on how long it takes on average to answer each question.  This could then be put into a logistic regression model as an controlling explanatory variable (you would expect an uninteresting positive coefficient - more don't knows for harder questions), and sequence of the question as an explanatory variable (with the idea of testing that one for significance).  Neither effect is likely to be linear, so some careful model building would be required; a generalized additive model might be one option.  The same approach could incorporate other question characteristics too eg number of options.

Ultimately, as suggested in my comment, if you need to prove this conclusively one way or another the only way is to randomise the order of questions (or groups of questions).

Comment: I have no information on the drop-outs (it's secondary data), but the mode of assessment was face-to-face interviewing so I expect little drop-out. Also the question order was not random. And unfortunately there is no data on timing per question. But I can estimate the question complexity myself. Thanks, and I will have a look at your suggestions.